# Why findFirstVisibleItemPosition doesn't work as expected?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am struggling with this issue for a long time I am trying to replace my listview with recyclerview and my listview looks like this:-

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/browser_sub_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="340dp"/>
```

Now when I call

```
view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

On this listview I returns the position of first item which is zero and as I have given top padding so it will keep returning only zero till the first item is out of screens bound.

But when I am trying to do the same thing with recyclerview even if the first item of recyclerview is visible still it gives me different values of firstvisible item and it happens because recyclerview considers toppadding as screen bound now I don't have any clue how to solve this problem.
Please help.

Here is my code.

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private TheAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            items.add("This is item:-" + i);
        }

        adapter = new TheAdapter(items);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                Log.d("DISTANCE", "" + linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="340dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my adapter class

```
class TheAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    public TheAdapter(ArrayList<String> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> mData;

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new ItemHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mData.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mData == null ? 0 : mData.size();
    }

    public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is totally wild and the behavior is counter-intuitive. Do you have a reference that this is the correct behavior? It looks like `android:clipToPadding="false"` is not honored by `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any reference, but technically this should be the case if first item is still visible then why to jump and go to second one android:clipToPadding="false" is honored in listview. May b i should post the sample project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until you find a better answer, you can try the following code. `int pos` is the position reported by `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`. This method will return the topmost visible position in the `RecyclerView`.

```
public int findRealFirstVisibleItemPosition(int pos) {
    View view;
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager =
            (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    while (pos > 0) {
        view = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(pos - 1);
        if (view == null) {
            break;
        }
        pos = pos - 1;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

I seem to recall that large padding causes these type of scrolling views problems.

Comment: great perfect answer if accepted but I had to any idea how to deal with it if it's gridlayoutmanager with two columns all because it was returning me in this order like 0,2,4 which is obviously true so I divided the position/2 but its nearly perfect if you have any solution with gridlayoutmanger too please update it for that also.